# main module can't read my service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a function which is in a service I have made. Whenever I try to search a username, I get an error which says "cannot read 'getUser' of undefined.

It shouldn't be undefined, I'm passing it an argument of a username it should be able to use. I can't seem to find out what's wrong with my service!

http://plnkr.co/edit/k4FD4eFuVKNvjEwKx2gs?p=preview

Any help to move forward with this would be appreciated :)

```
(function(){

  var github = function($http){

    var getUser = function(username){
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
        .then(function(response){
          return response.data; //still returns a promise
        });
    };
    //angular invokes this, return an object which is github service

    var getRepos = function(user){
      $http.get(user.repos_url).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      });
    };

    return {
      getUser: getUser,
      getRepos: getRepos
    };

  };

  var module = angular.module("firstapp"); //get reference to existing module, NOT creating a new one
  //register service with angular
  module.factory("github", github);
}());
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("firstapp", []) //defining module, no dependencies (so far)
  .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", function(
    $scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github) {
      $scope.search = function(username) {
        $log.info("Searching for "+username);
        //the first parameter to .then is only invokes onusercomplete if the get is successful
        //if error, it goes to second parameter which provdes error details
        github.getUser(username)
          .then(onUserComplete, onError);
        if (countdownInterval){
          $interval.cancel(countdownInterval);
          $scope.countDown = null;
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `getUser` function. You are not returning a promise there. To work the way you are using it it should look like

```
var getUser = function(username){
      return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username);
};
```

**EDIT1**
In your code, you were not returning a promise but the data returned by the promise.

Furthermore, you were returning that data from an anonymous callback (your `function(response) {...}`) to its caller (in your case `then(...)`

**EDIT2**

You should also check the way you are injecting your dependencies

```
.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", function(
                                $scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github) {
```

should be

```
.controller("MainController", ["$scope", '$http', "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", "github", function(
                                $scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github) {
```

**EDIT3**

You should also change the getRepos method like we did for the other one from

```
 var getRepos = function(user){
      $http.get(user.repos_url).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      });
```

to

```
 var getRepos = function(user){
    return $http.get(user.repos_url);
  });
```

Comment: I changed this to return the promise to my script.js function that called it, but I'm still getting the undefined error message.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in bad sequence of dependency injection arguments. 
It is:

```
  .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", function(
        $scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github)
```

Should be:

```
  .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location","$http", function(
        $scope,github,$interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github,$http)
```

Parameters must be in correct order in DI.

If you encounter errors like:

```
"cannot read function name of undefined"
```

Then you should look for function calls and see what's wrong with object from which call goes. 
In this case it's something wrong with `github`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your controller definition you don't have your dependencies line up

```
 .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", function(
$scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github) {
```

your dependencies are:

```
"$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location"
```

but they are getting injected as

```
 $scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, github
```

You have to have the order line up otherwise you'll have the wrong dependency in the wrong variable, also you're not adding $http in your listed dependencies.